# Changing the current page of UIPageControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uipagecontrol

I have a `UIScrollView`, in which I have added another 20 `UIScrollView` as subview. After that on 20 `UIScrollView`, I have added 4 `UIImageView` as their subview. All things are happening programmatically. Now I want to use `UIPageControl` for `UIImageView` which will change its current page value when I scroll the images.

```
 UIScrollView
 |
 |_ _ _ ScrollView Sub1---- PageControl 1
 |      |
 |      |_ _ _ Image 1
 |      |_ _ _ Image 2
 |      |_ _ _ Image 3
 |      |_ _ _ Image 4
 |
 |_ _ _ ScrollView Sub2 ---- PageControl 2
 |      |
 |      |_ _ _ Image 1
 |      |_ _ _ Image 2 
 |      |_ _ _ Image 3
 |      |_ _ _ Image 4
 |_ _ _ 
 | 
 |_ _ _
 |
 |_ _ _ ScrollView Sub20 ---- PageControl 20
 |      |_ _ _ Image 1
 |      |_ _ _ Image 2
 |      |_ _ _ Image 3
 |      |_ _ _ Image 4
 |
```

Now my question is:
1)Should I have to add 20 `UIPageControl` programmatically or just use only one which can  handle all ScrollViews?

2) How can I handle current page value of different scroll Views? Because during scrolling of images, I can also scroll the `UIScrollView`.

PS: Number of `UIScrollView` and `UIImageView` may be vary. Above I mentioned maximum values.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to playaround with the height of your MainScrollView (the one that holds all the UIScrollView subviews) and make use of `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` method from UIScrollView delegate. The way it works is getting the current y position of my MainScrollView contentOffset and divide it by the height of my MainScrollView. Below code might give you some idea: (Considering that you have a vertical UIScrollView)

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

if(scrollView == MAINS_SCROLLVIEW)
{
        CGFloat pageHeight = MAIN_SCROLLVIEW.frame.size.height; // getting the height

        int pageNo = round(formScrollView.contentOffset.y / pageHeight); // getting the page Number 
        pageControl.currentPage = pageNo; // Setting the page Number to pageControl
        NSLog(@"%i", pageNo);
        }
}
```

[image]

The above image is my view. I have three controls.. pageControl has been added inside the MainView and not in the UIScrollVIew.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Should I have to use different different UIPageControl for every UIScrollView?

Comment: You will only need to only one UIPageControl and then you can set currentPage to it. Try the above code creating a UIPageControl named pageControl.. Do not forget to set a delegate to your MAINSCROLLVIEW

Comment: On which UIScrollView I would add the pageControl? When I scroll the view, pagecontrol also scroll with it and then there is no pageControl show on current screen.

Comment: You have to add the pageControl on your view (which holds all the scrollViews). If you add the pageControl inside your UIScrollView, it will scroll.. Have added an image for your reference.